# Do I need to change client code to work with HTTPS as a replacement of HTTP on my API server?

Tags: node.js, api, ssl, client

I have setup SSL on my web API server with https://letsencrypt.org/. Now, knowing a bit more than zero about how SSL works, I suppose I need to apply changes to client code so that it could get the certificate from the server before doing actual requests?

Is it correct that if I used plain HTTP before and then switched to HTTPS, I need to do requests from clients apps differently?

Or, is it something that usually works seamlessly out of the box so I don't need to think if it's a secured connection or not?

Answer (score 1):

You need to explicitly send requests to HTTPS instead of HTTP. Of course, there are other ways to enforce ssl (Like redirecting all requests from HTTP to HTTPS on the server).

To explicitly use HTTPS, change all your urls referencing your server (That means `<a>` tags, `<img>` tags, `<script>`, `<style>`, etc.. anything that requests anything from your server) from http://... to https://...

Another thing to note: When a website is served over HTTPS, all resources requested by that website also needs to be requested over HTTPS, not only your own stuff. So if you are using css, images, scripts and such from other sources than your own server, you need to use the HTTPS versions of those as well. If you dont't do this, the browser will mark your page as potentially unsafe, since you are assuming to run over a safe connection (HTTPS) but are fetching resources from an unsafe location (HTTP)

Comment: To clarify, all the cert stuff is handled by the browser on the client. No need to make client-side changes other than making sure everything is hitting HTTPS. As @Stian mentioned, I suggest setting-up a HTTP-->HTTPS redirect rule on your webserver.